# Few characters not shown properly in utf8 encoded web page

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

There has been some problem showing few characters such as `(acute), ¦ (broken bar) properly in webpage. Most of the characters are shown properly like β, ç are shown properly. But I am fail to understand the problem with only few characters.

My database connection is utf8, the column I am storing data is utf8 and it's being stored properly. My html page encoding is utf8.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Edit:
The troubled characters are shown as �.
Also if I use iconv function like this `iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);` it removes the character.

Also one thing I noticed is that the characters not being shown up correctly are all ISO-8859-1 Symbols as per this link [HTML ISO-8859-1 reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)
Thanks.

Comment: How are the characters displayed? Btw the acute ` is an ASCII character, if it's not shown correctly this isn't just an encoding problem..

Comment: @JoniSalonen  I have edited the question with more info. Can you tell me if there is any workaround to show these kind of character?

Comment: What you show is a sign of an invalid character (like e.g. a ISO-8859-1 one) being shown in UTF-8 output. Are you 10000% sure those characters are stored properly in your database? Can you show the code you are using to set the database to UTF-8, and to output the data?

Comment: @Pekka Yes..I have double checked that it is being stored properly. I am using `SET NAMES 'utf8'` query on each php page before fetching the data. Let me know if you require more info.

Comment: I concur with Pekka, looks like invalid utf8 data. How are these characters shown when viewed in ISO-8859-1? e.g. in Firefox View->Character Encoding->Western

Comment: Ok. If I encode it with ISO-8859-1 using browser, it's shown properly. So these characters are encoded as ISO-8859-1 in database. But I fail to understand few things. Why it's shown properly in database with column encoded as utf8? Why this happen with only few characters as others are stored perfectly and works fine with utf8 encoded web page?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and set character set like ('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1') while fetching data

```
html_entity_decode('Your content', ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1')
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the following in your HTML:

```
&acute;  (acute)
&brvbar; (broken bar)
```

Seems to work on this site in any case:

´
¦

This site has more information:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm